# Zip stored 0%, should I be concerned?

Tags: zip

I am using `zip` to archive a lot of files.  There are a few files I have that are small (they just contain one decimal number stored on one line).  After operating on these files, `zip` reports `stored 0%`.  Not `deflated 0%`, but `stored 0%`.  I am wondering if this means that my subsequent zip archive will not have these files stored.  If so, is there any way I can fix it so `zip` will store them?  Is it because the files are so small?

Comment: Probably just a rounding error. Why not try extracting them and see if they come back out properly?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I zipped just the file in question, got the same "stored 0%" report, extracted it and the file was there in one piece, so everything is fine. Thanks for the suggestion, although I should have thought myself to try that first.

Comment: Good question, I had interpreted the output of zip of "stored 0%" as zero percent was being stored, scary. When its actually <compression-technique> <compression-percentage-gained>. So, no reason to be concerned.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When `zip` add a file, it will compress it if it makes sense.

If the file is big enough, `zip` will use the compression algorithm [`DEFLATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)  (and print "deflated" and the % gained with the compression).

For very small files the compression will make the result bigger (for example, if I manually deflate a file with 2 bytes, I will get 4 bytes) so `zip` decides to `STORE` them (no compression) : it prints "stored" and 0% because this "compression" didn't change the size. `zip` will also `STORE` folders (no content).

You can easily play with the compression : `zip -0` will `STORE` everything, `zip -1` to `zip -9` will change the compression level of `DEFLATE` and `zip -Z bzip2` will change the compression method.

So, to answer to your question : the `stored 0%` is fine ! The file has been added but not compressed.

Answer (score 54):

Do you run zip with recursion option?

```
zip -r output.zip folder
```

Without `-r`, the zip will not compress with sub-directories and lead to deflated 0%.

Comment: This was the solution to the issue I faced. I had forgotten to account for the sub-folders.